# Economic move from agricultural to manufacture to service in ?what after service sector?

Tags: macroeconomics

is there anything after service sector .in oecd nation most of employment in service sector.is there anything like post service world.

Answer (score 2):

No.

There is nothing in the economic literature on a post-service world. It is true that the development of most countries follows the agriculture -> manufacturing -> service pattern. There is nothing to suggest another sector coming after services.

Comment: thank you .Is there sub sector movement of labour between in services.american economy is service economy.so growth is going to stop.

Comment: @vaibhavshukla It isn't binary, the american economy is not entirely made up of service industries. In fact it has a booming agricultural sector.